# Search CSV file to find a specific value without specifying column name with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

Is there a way to search a .CSV file row by row looking for a specific value without having to specify column names to search in, would like to run this script on multiple .CSV files so specifying column names isn't an option to me.

Sample PowerShell code:

```
foreach ($row in $csvFile){
    if ($row -eq/-contains $StringIWantToFind) {
        #do something with the string here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't care about which colum the (sub)string is in you could use a wildcard match:

```
$row -like "*$StringIWantToFind*"
```

or a regular expression match:

```
$row -match $StringIWantToFind
```

The latter would probably be the better choice if you want to use the value for something, because it gives you match (and submatches) via the automatic variable `$matches`:

```
$StringIWantToFind = 'something (captured group) or other'

foreach ($row in $csvFile) {
    if ($row -match $StringIWantToFind) {
        # do something with $matches[0] (full match) or $matches[1] (captured
        # group) here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to do this would be to use a `Select-String`, something like this:

```
Select-String your_file.txt -Pattern 'string to find' -SimpleMatch
```

If you then want to process the results you can extract the matched lines like so:

```
Select-String your_file.txt -Pattern 'xx' -SimpleMatch | Select -ExpandProperty line | % {
  # your processing here using $_
}
```